# Issue reading value from text file and passing it into if conditions

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make this batch file read a .txt and use the value it finds (1,2 or 3) to select a song to play. I have written this but it only works if the .txt reads 1 but 2 and 3 do not work.

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (startsong.txt) do set ransongforintropicker=%%i
IF %ransongforintropicker% == 1 set ransongforintro=BloodMoon_by_VeoRug.mp3
IF %ransongforintro% == BloodMoon_by_VeoRug.mp3 set ransongforintrotext=Song: Blood Moon By VeoRug
IF %ransongforintropicker% == 2 timeout /t -1
IF %ransongforintro% == Invincible_by_VeoRug.mp3 set ransongforintrotext=Song: Invincible By VeoRug
IF %ransongforintropicker% == 3 set ransongforintro=GoldenMove_by_VeoRug.mp3
IF %ransongforintro% == GoldenMove_by_VeoRug set ransongforintrotext=Song: Golden Move By VeoRug
```

Could someone please tell me how to fix this or tell me of a better way to do this?

Comment: You could try to use the right tool for the job. Batch files are awful for this kind of task.

Comment: Well what do you recommend?

Comment: PowerShell would do nicely. It's a scripting language that's significantly more powerful than batch files and is bundled with Windows.

Comment: Oh, please. PowerShell is disgustingly verbose. The only time it's necessary to use PowerShell over batch is if you're doing math with non-integers or numbers larger than 2^31, or if you need to interact with GUIs. Batch is perfectly fine for this task. It's only not working here because you aren't using parentheses.

Comment: In supplement to @SomethingDark comment on PowerShell vs. Batch (I would like confirm it):  could you provide a sample of `startsong.txt` if it contains more than either `1` or `2` or `3`

Comment: startsong.txt only contained the number 1, 2, or 3 depending on which was chosen with the batch file that created the document. At the moment I have it just the number 2.

Comment: and @SomethingDark where would the parentheses go? Sorry I am kinda new at this, I am trying to learn.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. "Issue in a windows batch file" has absolutely no meaning (both windows and batchfile are in your tags, meaning your entire subject line is "issue in file"). Your title should describe the **specific** problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will be useful to a future reader here who finds it in a search result. "2 and 3 do not work" also has no meaning unless you explain specifically **how** they do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I'm finally back in front of an actual keyboard, I can address the problems with your script more properly. If you absolutely *must* keep the format in your original post, your code isn't working with `2` or `3` because your `if` statements are incorrect.

`IF %ransongforintropicker% == 2 timeout /t -1` runs the `timeout` command when your file contains `2`, but then it **doesn't set the ransongforintro variable**, so your if statement evaulates to `IF   == 2`, which will always return false.

In your very last `if` statement, you check the value of `%ransongforintro%` against GoldenMove_by_VeoRug, but in the statement before it, you set that variable to GoldenMove_by_VeoRug **.mp3**, so your if statement evaluates to `IF 
GoldenMove_by_VeoRug == GoldenMove_by_VeoRug.mp3`, which (again) will always return false.

---

Expanding on my comment, using parentheses would prevent you from setting variables to the incorrect values (which is why 3 isn't working) or forgetting to set them altogether (which is why 2 isn't working).

Also, I've shortened the variable names because I'm posting from my phone.

```
@echo off
for /F %%A in (startsong.txt) do set ransong=%%A

if %ransong%==1 (
    set song=BloodMoon_by_VeoRug.mp3
    set "songtitle=Blood Moon by VeoRug"
)
if %ransong%==2 (
    set song=Invincible_by_VeoRug.mp3
    set "songtitle=Invincible by VeoRug"
)
if %ransong%==3 (
    set song=GoldenMove_by_VeoRug.mp3
    set "songtitle=Golden Move by VeoRug"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You encounter issues with variables expanding at execution time. You need to add at the top of your script:

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

A reworking of your code (preserving your existing structure) is below it may clarify matters:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set trackchoice=0
set trackfile=0
set trackinfo=0

for /f %%i in (trackchoice.txt) do set trackchoice=%%i

if %trackchoice% == 1 set trackfile=Lateralus.mp3
   if %trackfile% == Lateralus.mp3 (
      set trackinfo=Track: Lateralus
      echo %trackfile%
      echo !trackinfo! & echo.Artist: Tool
      pause
      )

if %trackchoice% == 2 set trackfile=Schism.mp3
    if %trackfile% == Schism.mp3 (
      set trackinfo=Track: Schism
      echo %trackfile%
      echo !trackinfo! & echo.Artist: Tool
      pause
      )
```

If you want to play the .mp3 at any point you can do so by using the [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

Script: modified by *@SomethingDark* where would the parentheses go:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (startsong.txt) do (
    set ransongforintropicker=%%i
    if %%i equ 1 (
        set ransongforintro=BloodMoon_by_VeoRug.mp3
        set ransongforintrotext=Song: Blood Moon By VeoRug
    )
    if %%i equ 2 (
        rem timeout /t -1
        set ransongforintro=Invincible_by_VeoRug.mp3
        set ransongforintrotext=Song: Invincible By VeoRug
    )
    if %%i equ 3 (
        set ransongforintro=GoldenMove_by_VeoRug.mp3
        set ransongforintrotext=Song: Golden Move By VeoRug
    )
)
echo ransongforintropicker %ransongforintropicker%
echo ransongforintro       %ransongforintro%
echo ransongforintrotext   %ransongforintrotext%
```

Output:

```
==>echo ^1>startsong.txt

==>..\29291082.bat
ransongforintropicker 1
ransongforintro       BloodMoon_by_VeoRug.mp3
ransongforintrotext   Song: Blood Moon By VeoRug

==>echo ^2>startsong.txt

==>..\29291082.bat
ransongforintropicker 2
ransongforintro       Invincible_by_VeoRug.mp3
ransongforintrotext   Song: Invincible By VeoRug

==>echo ^3>startsong.txt

==>..\29291082.bat
ransongforintropicker 3
ransongforintro       GoldenMove_by_VeoRug.mp3
ransongforintrotext   Song: Golden Move By VeoRug

==>echo ^4>startsong.txt

==>..\29291082.bat
ransongforintropicker 4
ransongforintro
ransongforintrotext

==>
```

Comment: Why bother sticking the entire thing in the `for` loop? The text file only contains one character. Heck, it would probably be simpler to just say `set /p ransongforintropicker=<startsong.txt` instead of having a loop at all!

Comment: Your _parentheses_ idea gone to  all lengths :)  @SomethingDark :) However, `set /p ransongforintropicker=<startsong.txt` notion seems to be an excellent solution...